# Message Queue Implementation

Tags: php, message-queue, rabbitmq

I'm looking for the fastest way to log a message without having the producer connect to any server when sending out the log.  The best case scenario would be just log the message to something local really fast (memory, local message queue) and then exits.  Then a separate process dequeues it and send it to an actual consumer (probably with a persistent connection).  This helps reduce processing speed on the producer process (e.g. a web server handle) by preventing an extra connection.

Would RabitMQ using PHP be something of my interest?

Comment: when you say you don't want the producer to to connect to any server do you mean a physical external server?  I am confused because connecting to a local message queue is essentially connecting to a server, even if they are on the same hardware.

Comment: @robthewolf yes I sort of meant it that way, but there's also the IPC message queue which acts more like a system call than an actual tcp connection.  So I was thinking 1 local set of producer-consumer using IPC mq and a network level producer-consumer.  The key difference would be the interface to users would respond as fast as possible while the process behind handles them in serial.

Answer (score 1):

Logstash (http://www.logstash.net/) sets up listeners on local logfiles of your choice, then sends them as messages via AMQP (RabbitMQ, last I checked in 2012), to a central log store/database of your choice (say, a mongoDB instance).

You can customize a Logstash listener to filter out only certain, interesting log message types/codes from a log file before sending it to the queue broker.

After that, you can set up Graylog2 (http://graylog2.org/) as a useful interface for reading, sorting and filtering your logs originating from all your servers, organized in one view in chronological order (assuming your server times are sufficiently in synch).

Answer (score 0):

As @robthewolf points out in his comment, connecting to a message queue is an extra connection, whether locally or not. Also, I am not sure what exactly you mean by "processing" (formatting the messages? displaying the logs?).

From what you describe, I think you should look into [Graylog](http://graylog2.org/about). You could use [Monolog](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog) with [Gelf-PHP](https://github.com/mlehner/gelf-php) to send your log messages via AMQP to your Graylog-Server.

Answer (score 0):

The solution you proposed would work. But there is every chance of message build up on the in-memory queue as the producer who is actually connecting to messaging server may not be able to send messages to messaging server as the logs will be put into memory queue at much faster rate.